# Clone checkbox when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

I want to be able to clone a checkbox when it is clicked, and the cloned checkbox will be unchecked. When the cloned checkbox is checked, it will clone itself and the process repeats.

```
                        <section class="misc"> 
                    <div class="row">
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <label class="label"><input type="checkbox" class="others"> Others:</label>                     
                    </div>           

                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Others"/></div>                          
                    </div>
                    </section>
                    <div class="sth"></div>

                <!-- Clone the "Others" checkbox with textbox when the original checkbox is checked. I want each subsequent clone to be unchecked, then clone itself.. -->
                <script>
                $(".others").change(function(){

                 if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    {
                        var clone=$(this).parents('section').clone();
                        $('.sth').html(clone);
                    }

                });</script>
```

Right now, I'm only able to clone the original and the cloned checkbox is checked instead of unchecked.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLkvxydh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To unchecked the new created checkbox you can use `.find('.others:checkbox').prop('checked' , false).end();`
- if you need to use the click event for the dynamically generated `checkbox` you'll need to use `$(document).on('change',".others" ,function(){`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="misc"> 
    <div class="row">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <label class="label"><input type="checkbox" class="others"> Others:</label>                     
    </div>           

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Others"/></div>                          
    </div>
    </section>
    <div class="sth"></div>
<!-- Clone the "Others" checkbox with textbox when the original checkbox is checked. I want each subsequent clone to be unchecked, then clone itself.. -->
<script>
$(document).on('change',".others" ,function(){

 if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var clone=$(this).parents('section').clone().find('.others:checkbox').prop('checked' , false).end();
        $('.sth').append(clone);
    }

});</script>
```

**Note:** By using `html()` in `$('.sth').html(clone);` it will change the whole html again and again so you'll not notice the effect of the code .. So I changed `html(` to `append(` to let you see the code is work